# Equivalent to rails console in nodeJS express

Tags: node.js

I am from Ruby on Rails background, is there is anything similar like `rails c` in nodeJS with express.

What is the right way to properly debug the node express project code

Answer (score 1):

So, something to realize is that nodejs is a lower-Level framework that’s Rails is.  It’s not going to be opinions about how you do your routing, data modeling, etc.  there are very few conventions inherent to nodejs itself.

To that end, if all you want is a rails-style REPL at the command line, just type “node” at your command line and you have it.  It’s not going to be baked in with any of your application context like the rails console will, though, so you’ll for example have to require any modules you want to play with.

Most folks gravitate to frameworks sitting on top of node to give them whatever amount of structural guidance and helpers they are comfortable with.  Since you’re coming from rails I will recommend you look at Express (something like Sinatra) if you want to do a basic web application or API, and Sails (uses Express under the hood but provides a lot of the generators, data modeling conventions and so on that you might already be comfortable with).

As for debugging, there are many options but if you’re going with sails, they do have an interactive debugger and other console tools that might be what you’re interested in. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-console

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure about how you do it in RoR. But in node.js you can use a module called PM2

[PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

This will help you to cluster, monitor and log the logs of a application. Pm2 will also generate log files that you can use with elastic search for production server logging.

Comment: `rails c` is totally different thing than PM2. PM2 helps you manage and monitor whereas `rails c` helps you debug mostly.